# Control Instantiation of objects without restricting constructor access

Tags: c#

When we want to control instantiation of objects, we often make the constructor private or internal:

```
public class A {
    private A(int aParam) { }
}
```

However, this is essentially the same as sealing the class 'A' because now no one can inherit from it.

So, we can make the constructor protected:

```
public class A {
    protected A(int aParam) { }
}
public class B {
    protected B(int aParam) : base(aParam) { }
}
```

However, this means that any code from B (or any class derived from it) can instantiate a new A.

I am looking for a way to control instantiation but without having to make classes sealed (effectively or otherwise).

Note: I know that classes can always be instantiated with reflection and other tricks anyway; I'm only interested in creating an explicit 'contract'. If someone wants to subvert my contract deliberately that's up to them.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How about a private constructor and a public static method that does logic + instansiation?

Comment: @Alxandr That sounds like a factory pattern to me

Comment: @Alxandr Then I wouldn't be able to inherit...

Comment: When you say "control instantiation," do you mean you want to ensure that certain initialization code is always run?

Comment: @harpo No, I want to prevent people from creating an instance of A or B- I want them to go through my factory.

Comment: @Motig As soon as you let somebody make a subclass, you lose that control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure what you mean. If am not wrong then you're trying to prevent instantiation of `Base Class` from `Derived Class` Right?

That is the default behavior too. You cannot instantiate base class from derived class when your base class constructor is `protected`.

```
class Program
{
    A a = A.CreateInstance();//works
    B b = B.CreateInstanceOfB();//works
    A ab = B.CreateInstanceOfA();//wont work
}

public class A
{
    protected A()
    {

    }
    public static A CreateInstance()
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected B()
        : base()//
    {

    }
    public static B CreateInstanceOfB()
    {
        return new B();
    }
    public static A CreateInstanceOfA()
    {
        return new A();//This wont compile CS1540: Cannot access protected member...
    }
}
```

Protected constructor is intended to invoke through constructor chaining(using base keyword) only. You can't instantiate it without reflection.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

> I am looking for a way to control instantiation but without having to make classes sealed (effectively or otherwise).

This is really contradictory in your requirements.

If you want to allow subclasses to be created, you *must* allow the subclass to effectively create the parent, which means you need to have, at a minimum, one `protected` constructor.  Without this, there would be no way for the subclass to initialize the instance properly.

By exposing a constructor as protected, you allow subclasses to change the instantiation rules (they can always add a public constructor).

There are really only two options here:

1. Make the constructor protected, and assume that the subclass will do the "right thing" (whatever that is in your scenario), or
2. Seal your class, and then expose the construction method you choose.  This prevents subclasses, but does not prevent your class from being reused via composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to instantiate subclasses, but prohibit explicit instantiation of a base class, then you have two options:

- Add a pure virtual method thus making the base class abstract.
- Add a protected constructor, and overload the "new" operator to disallow explicit instantiation of the base class, even though it's not abstract.

Comment: That would work great for C++; but this is a question about C#.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the second option. The first however is appropriate for C# also.